# Android:Quick Search Box - Adding Custom Suggestions

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android and trying to implement Quick Search Dialog for my application.

Actually, in my application I have an activity 
1. where I have a Edit text and Search Button next to it
2. Add Button and a Employee Table below it.

Whenever the user enters the search string in the EditText and clicks the Search button , I am calling the Quick Search Box and luckily it opens with the Search and here the user can see the given search query.
Till this, every thing works perfectly as I want.

But what I want is:
On-Clicking the Search button,the search query is displayed in the QSB and what I want is to display custom suggestions based on the search query and selecting the valid data , it should be saved in the Employee table.

Now I want Custom Suggestions to be displayed in a list view based on the search query.
How do I proceed to achieve this.

Please provide links for Quick search Box custom suggestions also.

Thanks and Regards,
Fazal Ahamed B

Answer (score 0):

This is described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html